# Export react-styleguidist documentation

Tags: reactjs, pdf, export, documentation, react-styleguidist

I am using simple comments which react-styleguidist exports to documentation. There is `npx styleguidist server` which runs it on server and `npx styleguidist build` which makes a bundle file.

Is there any way I can export this documentation. For example, in pdf or some other format that I can send to somebody?

Answer (score 1):

Not something specific to react or styleguidist but you can always go to print the page and instead of the destination set to a printer, you can set it to save as a PDF

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your use case, but could make more sense to publish the generated files (after `npx styleguidist build`) somewhere like GitHub Pages, and send a link.

Comment: Hy Artem, thanks for the help. Can you please elaborate how I would do that. After I run build how would I put that on github so that I can youst send the link to someone and he can see the generated documentation?

Comment: Using [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) module for example. It's just a static HTML, you can host it anywhere you like.